# Javascript .pathname IE quirk?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Consider the following Javascript:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i < anchors.length; i++)
{
    alert(a.pathname);
}
```

When I run this on a page that contains links in the format "http://foo.com/bar", in IE8 I get back a string that looks like "bar".  In Safari, Chrome, Firefox, I get back something like "/bar" (note the leading forward slash).

Is IE at fault here, what's the deal?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/02/28/internet-explorer-window-location-pathname-missing-slash-and-host-has-port.aspx

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150104045133/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/02/28/internet-explorer-window-location-pathname-missing-slash-and-host-has-port.aspx

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [W3C standard on the window object](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location-attributes) - including the location interface - is dated 07 April 2006, ie it was specified after actual implementations had been around for years.

The standard reads:

> **pathname**
>
> This attribute represents the path component of the Location's URI which consists of everything after the host and port up to and excluding the first question mark (?) or hash mark (#).

This means the leading slash should be included, which is consistent with [Mozilla's implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Location_object).

The [MSDN doc on the location object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534332(VS.85).aspx) doesn't mention what the property contains, but a [page on the VBScript location object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970635.aspx) has an example consistent with your discovery.

As said page is ©1996 - ten years before the W3C got involved - it's hardly fair to say that IE is at fault, but I'd still consider it a bug.

Comment: A bug report has been filed with the IE dev team for this issue. It only occurs for `<a>` tags that are not added to the document itself. The workaround is to either add it to the document before grabbing `pathname` or just check to see if the resulting string starts with a `/`. More info here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1002846

Answer (score 18):

The odd thing about this behavior is that **window.location.pathname** returns the leading slash (after the hostname) in all versions of IE, same as all other browsers.

It is only the location object of a hyperlink ('a element') that returns the path without the slash in IE (and Opera as well).

Comment: Opera now includes the leading slash as of 10.x.