# Getting pathnames (relative to host) from <a> with href="../foo/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, relative-path

The following code will return as `undefined`:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).pathname);
});

My anchors look like this:
<a href="../foo/">Foo</a>
```

What am I doing wrong? If it is not possible then how can I return the full url?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807674/get-pathname-from-href-in-javascript

Comment: Don't know why I'm downvoted but that question has absolute url. Mine does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML5 browsers you can use `this.pathname`:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    console.log(this.pathname);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6BpWG/)

`pathname` is a property of the [Anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAnchorElement), not of a jQuery object.

Edit: The anchor's `pathname` property has been standardized in HTML5, but even IE6 supports it natively.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`$(this).attr('href')`

The `.attr()` method extracts an attribute. You can see the docs at http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: It will give `../foo/` which isn't the pathname (relative to host).