# Make active links with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexof

I am making active link with jQuery like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    $(".main-navigation ul li a").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);

        var href = $this.attr("href");

        if (url === href) {

            $this.css({
                'color': '#666666',
                'font-weight': 'bold',
            }).addClass('active').removeAttr("href").removeAttr("onclick");         
        }           
    });
```

The only problem is here that my a href goes like this /Settings/File?id=333

And url wil be something like this

```
http://www.example.com/Settings/File?id=333
```

Then the a href and ulr does not match, how to delete http and example for url and check with a href?

Comment: not sure if we can do $this instead of $( this )

Comment: This is working ok, the problem is with http://www.example.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get pathname from href in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807674/get-pathname-from-href-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: if you are going to give them a class anyway, don't put extra inline CSS there...

And here a snipper that should work...

```
var uri = window.location.href;
$(".main-navigation ul li a").filter(function() {
    return (this.href == uri || uri.substr(0,this.href.length + 1) == this.href + "?");
}).css({
    'color': '#666666',
    'font-weight': 'bold',
}).addClass('active').removeAttr("href").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `/Settings/File?id=333` use :

```
$this[0].pathname;
```

[Get pathname from href in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807674/get-pathname-from-href-in-javascript)

[Location pathname Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp)

Comment: This is ok, when i have .com, the problem is that i dont know it will be .com

Comment: window.location.pathname gives you JUST the path :-)

Comment: @DoXicK and to `$this.attr("href");` ?

Comment: split it at the first / after http(s)://

Comment: @Schneider see my edit use [Location pathname Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_pathname.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You want to change `http://www.example.com/Setting/File?id=333` into `/Setting/File?id=333`?

```
var url = window.location.href.split('.com').pop();
```

If you don't know if it's a .com website, try this:

```
function getLocation(url) {
    var el = document.createElement("a");
    el.href = url;
    return el.pathname;
}

var url = getLocation(window.location.href);
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem is .com?? I dont know it wolud be .com?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the native a element DOM and its href it will give the full url:

```
$(function(){
  var url = window.location.href;

  $(".main-navigation ul li a").each(function() {
    if (url === this.href) {
      $(this).css({
        'color': '#666666',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
      }).addClass('active').removeAttr("href").removeAttr("onclick");
    }
  });
});
```

[example on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lodegu/1/edit) (first item in the list has the same url without the domain)