# How can I tell if a user is on index.html?

Tags: javascript, url, document, detection

I use document.URL to detect if a user is on index.html:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("index") >-1) return true;
```

But if the user types "mydomain.com" or "mydomain.com/" then the test returns false.

I could try:

```
if(document.URL ==="http://myDomain.com") return true;
```

But I want to use this code on different domains. Any suggestions?

Comment: does this have to be done with javascript? can it be done with PHP?

Comment: Wouldn't PHP have to be online? The page is a Javascript game, and I want the users to have the option to save it onto disk. So if page detection is all Javascript that's a bonus.

Comment: ok, I think that's an example of you needing to provide more info :-P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are so many permutations of URL that *could* mean that a user is on `index.html`. Instead could you not put a var within that file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    on_index = true;
</script>
```

Just check if `on_index` is not undefined and is true. That'll be accurate 100% of the time.

Comment: Thanks. Accuracy is essential, so I'll use this method.

Comment: Please, sentences do not end in commas.

Answer (score 7):

javascript [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) has many useful properties, in particular, you can examine `location.pathname`.

Basically, you're on the "index" page if the pathname is 1) empty 2) is equal to a slash `/` 3) starts with `index` or `/index`.

```
 var p = window.location.pathname;

 if (p.length === 0 || p === "/" || p.match(/^\/?index/))
     alert ("on the index page!")
```

See [Javascript .pathname IE quirk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956233/javascript-pathname-ie-quirk) for the discussion of leading slash issues.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct link between files and URLs. Additionally, `index.html` does not need to be in the site's root and the default page does not need to be `index.html`.

If you want a generic solution, you're probably out of luck. If you want a solution for your particular case, you can just provide that info from the page itself, e.g. defining an ID or class name:

```
<body class="index">
```

... or a JavaScript variable:

```
// Pick one
var page = 'index';
var isIndex = true;
```

If all you want is some simple string manipulation with current location, grab the `pathname` property of the `window.location` object:

```
// Untested
if( window.location.pathname=="/" || window.location.pathname=="/index.html" ){
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
if (document.location.pathname === '/' || 
    document.location.pathname.indexOf('index') >-1 ) {
   return true;
 }
```

If you have access to the actual page and not just the script then you should follow [@Ben Everard's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8989887/128165) advice.

Just make sure you include the snippet he proposes before your script..