# Overwrite width of an div element with jquery - IE bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have problem with a very simple jquery script - it works with all browsers except IE. Basically I want to change the width of a div element with jquery. IE explorer seems to ignore the change. Here is the complete script (only at certain pages, I want to have that change):

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  var a, url = document.URL;;
  a = document.createElement( 'a' );
  a.href = url;
  if (a.pathname == '/index.php/somepage')
  $("div.component.message").css("width","700px");
 });
</script>
```

The part that doesn't work is with IE (IE 11/ Edge):

```
$("div.component.message").css("width","700px");
```

If I put something else in the if clause like an alert it will be executed. The width change does work in Opera, Chrome oder Firefox.

I solved the problem in the php file, which might be better than doing it with javascript in the first place, still I'd like to know if I simply made a stupid mistake or if it is a problem with IE in general.

Comment: why don't you use `if (window.pathname == '/index.php/somepage')`

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Haven't done much with javascript / jquery yet and likely do many things still fairly clumsy. Unfortunally it doesn't solve the IE problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.pathname` returns the `leading slash after the hostname` in all versions of IE

The `<a>` tag is only that returns the path without the slash in IE (and Opera as well).

Check [Javascript .pathname IE quirk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956233/javascript-pathname-ie-quirk)

Answer (score 0):

You've written double semi-colon at this

```
var a, url = document.URL;;
```

This might be a problem. Correct it.